# How to add nested context menu - visual studio addin

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I created the extension for Visual Studio 2015 which looks [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByXcN.png)

But i want to place all the four menus in a category say *My Group*. Which should like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlNJG.png).

- My Group [On click of this the rest of submenus shoud come same as shown in the image]

  - menu one
  - menu two

My vsct file looks like this

```
<Commands package="package">    
    <Groups>
      <Group guid="PackageCmdSet" id="MenuGroup" priority="0x0300">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE"/>
      </Group>

      <Group guid="ClassPackageCmdSet" id="ProjectMenuGroup" priority="0x0400">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJNODE"/>
      </Group>
    </Groups>
```

and i have buttons like this

```
 <Buttons>    
      <Button guid="PackageCmdSet" id="BranchModelClassId" priority="0x0100" type="Button" >
        <Parent guid="PackageCmdSet" id="MenuGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
        <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
        <Strings>
          <CommandName>Test</CommandName>
          <ButtonText>Test</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
```

How to created a nested menu which i shouwn in the second image ?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the way. The change has to be done in the vsct file.

Add menus first inside the Commands

```
  <Menus>
      <Menu guid="PackageCmdSet" id="MainMenu" priority="0x0100" type="Menu">
        <Parent guid="PackageCmdSet" id="MenuGroup" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Nested Menu</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Menu>
 <Menus>
```

Then add groups

```
<Groups>
      <Group guid="PackageCmdSet" id="MenuGroup" priority="0x0200">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE"/>
      </Group>

      <Group guid="PackageCmdSet" id="CommandsMenuGruop" priority="0x0300">
        <Parent guid="PackageCmdSet" id="MainMenu"/>
      </Group>
  <Groups>
```

The button should be like this

```
 <Buttons>
      <Button guid="PackageCmdSet" id="ClassId" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="PackageCmdSet" id="CommandsMenuGruop" />
        <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
        <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
        <Strings>
          <CommandName>Command</CommandName>
          <ButtonText>Item 1</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
  <Buttons>
```